# FedEx REST API (Upload Documents): Invalid request: invalid input: Incoming request [code 1001]

Tags: python, rest, fedex

I am trying to create a simple Python script to upload a PDF document via the new FedEx REST API.

Below is my minimal code example, which can be used to replicate the issue by placing a file, `file.pdf`, next to the script and updating to your own FedEx REST API production credentials.

In running the code, I get the below error message. Any inputs are appreciated:

```
{
    "customerTransactionId": "ETD-Pre-Shipment-Upload_test1",
    "errors": {
        "code": "1001",
        "message": "Invalid request: invalid input : Incoming Request"
    }
}
```

My code is below:

```
# minimal class for upload docs test
class FedexLabelHelper:
    def __init__(self, fedex_cred):
        self.fedex_cred = fedex_cred
        self.access_token = ""

        return

    # function for retrieving access_token
    def get_access_token(self):
        import json, requests

        url = self.fedex_cred["url_prefix"] + "/oauth/token"

        payload = {
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_id": self.fedex_cred["key"],
            "client_secret": self.fedex_cred["password"],
        }

        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

        response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        access_token = json.loads(response.text)["access_token"]
        self.access_token = access_token

 
    # function for uploading PDF document 
    def upload_pdf_document_fedex_script(self):
        import requests, binascii

        fileName = "file.pdf"

        file_content = open(fileName, "rb").read()
        file_content_b64 = binascii.b2a_base64(file_content)
        file_content_b64.decode("cp1250")

        url = self.fedex_cred["doc_url_prefix"] + "/documents/v1/etds/upload"

        payload = {
            "document": {
                "workflowName": "ETDPreshipment",
                "carrierCode": "FDXE",
                "name": fileName,
                "contentType": "application/pdf",
            },
            "meta": {
                "shipDocumentType": "COMMERCIAL_INVOICE",
                "originCountryCode": "DK",
                "destinationCountryCode": "BE",
            },
        }

        files = [
            (
                "attachment",
                (fileName, "file_content_b64", "application/pdf"),
            )
        ]

        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.access_token}",
            "x-customer-transaction-id": "ETD-Pre-Shipment-Upload_test1",
            "Cookie": "XYZ",
        }

        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

        print(response.text)

  
# -----------------------
# setup minimal test of the FedEx Upload Documents REST API
fedex_cred = {
    "production": {
        "url_prefix": "https://apis.fedex.com",
        "doc_url_prefix": "https://documentapi.prod.fedex.com",
        "key": "XYZ",
        "password": "XYZ",
        "freight_account_number": "XYZ",
    },
}

flh = FedexLabelHelper(fedex_cred["production"])
flh.get_access_token()
flh.upload_pdf_document_fedex_script()
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this via the updated function below:

```
def upload_pdf_document_fedex_script(self):
    import requests, binascii
    from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

    fileName = "file.pdf"

    file_content = open(fileName, "rb").read()
    file_content_b64 = binascii.b2a_base64(file_content)
    file_content_b64.decode("cp1250")

    url = self.fedex_cred["doc_url_prefix"] + "/documents/v1/etds/upload"

    payload = {
        "document": f'{{"workflowName": "ETDPreshipment", "carrierCode": "FDXE", "name": "{fileName}", "contentType": "application/pdf", "meta": {{"shipDocumentType": "COMMERCIAL_INVOICE", "originCountryCode": "DK", "destinationCountryCode": "BE"}}}}',
        "attachment": (fileName, file_content_b64, "application/pdf"),
    }

    m = MultipartEncoder(fields=payload)

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.access_token}",
        "x-customer-transaction-id": "ETD-Pre-Shipment-Upload_test1",
        "Content-Type": m.content_type,
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=m)

    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Absolute legend. This saved me.